# How do I build a complex array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

How can I build an array like this in PHP?

It should have unique keys each of whose corresponding values are arrays, and those arrays have multiple elements for each key.

```
Array (
    42 => Array ( 56, 86, 97 )
    51 => Array ( 64, 52 )
)
```

Comment: How do you build an array like that?  You just did.  Add a `,` after the 2nd line (`42 => Array ( 56, 86, 97 )`), and it's valid code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$main = array();
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
  // $i makes numeric keys
  $main[$i] = array();

  // Or instead, you could make a truly unique key name for each:
  $main[uniqid()] = array(...somevalues...);

}
```

Creates something like:

```
Array
(
    [4f105f361cdd1] => Array
        (
        )

    [4f105f361cf24] => Array
        (
        )

    [4f105f361cf33] => Array
        (
        )

    [4f105f361cf3c] => Array
        (
        )

    [4f105f361cf44] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$arr = array(
    42 => array(56, 86, 97),
    51 => array(64, 52)
);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arraytest = array(
           42 => array(56, 86, 97), 
           51 => array(64, 52)
           );

var_dump($arraytest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
  42 => array(56,86,97),
  51 => array(64,52)
);
```